# Problem with Error:(6, 60) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'schronisko'

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have searched the depths of the Internet and nothing seems to work...
In XML schema I have to include some structures, but I don't know if anything I included is the source of error or not.
I tried getting rid of namespace but it didn't help, sometimes I also get:
xsi:schemaLocation' is not allowed to appear in element 'schronisko'.
I have compared my work with the ones I found or got from other people, but didn't manage to get rid of the error.

**my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schronisko
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:schr="http://www.example.pl/schema"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.pl/schema z1.xsd">

    <schr:autor numer_albumu="123456">
        <schr:imie_autora>Abcd</schr:imie_autora>
        <schr:nazwisko>Bcdska</schr:nazwisko>
    </schr:autor>
    <schr:opis>Afdjngkfjogi vdsknlr</schr:opis>

    <!--Spis zwierząt-->
    <schr:zwierzeta>
        <schr:zwierze nr="z1" gatunek="kot">
            <schr:plec>F</schr:plec>
            <schr:imie>Malina</schr:imie>
            <schr:wielkosc>sredni</schr:wielkosc>
            <schr:wiek>4</schr:wiek>
            <schr:kolor>biały</schr:kolor>
            <schr:nr_chipa>123134434957263</schr:nr_chipa>
            <schr:data_przyjecia>03/2021</schr:data_przyjecia>
            <schr:miejsce_znalezienia mID="m1"></schr:miejsce_znalezienia>
        </schr:zwierze>
        <schr:zwierze nr="z2" gatunek="kot">
            <schr:plec>M</schr:plec>
            <schr:imie>Klebek</schr:imie>
            <rasa>perski</rasa>
            <schr:wielkosc>duzy</schr:wielkosc>
            <schr:waga jednostka="kg">5.8</schr:waga>
            <schr:wiek>3</schr:wiek>
            <schr:kolor>czarny</schr:kolor>
            <schr:kolor>biały</schr:kolor>
            <schr:nr_chipa>357834434957263</schr:nr_chipa>
            <schr:data_przyjecia>22-09-2021</schr:data_przyjecia>
            <schr:miejsce_znalezienia mID="m2"></schr:miejsce_znalezienia>
        </schr:zwierze>
        <schr:zwierze nr="z3" gatunek="kot">
            <schr:plec>F</schr:plec>
            <schr:imie>Kulka</schr:imie>
            <schr:wielkosc>sredni</schr:wielkosc>
            <schr:waga jednostka="kg">3.4</schr:waga>
            <schr:wiek>2</schr:wiek>
            <schr:kolor>rudy</schr:kolor>
            <schr:nr_chipa>468956314688763</schr:nr_chipa>
            <schr:data_przyjecia>22/09/2021</schr:data_przyjecia>
            <schr:miejsce_znalezienia mID="m2"></schr:miejsce_znalezienia>
        </schr:zwierze>
        <schr:zwierze nr="z4" gatunek="pies">
            <schr:plec>M</schr:plec>
            <schr:imie>Azor</schr:imie>
            <rasa>owczarek</rasa>
            <schr:wielkosc>duzy</schr:wielkosc>
            <schr:waga jednostka="kg">10.3</schr:waga>
            <schr:wiek>7</schr:wiek>
            <schr:nr_chipa>234567654323443</schr:nr_chipa>
            <schr:data_przyjecia>13/09/2021</schr:data_przyjecia>
            <schr:miejsce_znalezienia mID="m2"></schr:miejsce_znalezienia>
        </schr:zwierze>
        <schr:zwierze nr="z5" gatunek="pies">
            <schr:plec>M</schr:plec>
            <schr:imie>Fifi</schr:imie>
            <rasa>owczarek</rasa>
            <schr:wielkosc>duzy</schr:wielkosc>
            <schr:waga jednostka="kg">7.3</schr:waga>
            <schr:wiek>5</schr:wiek>
            <schr:nr_chipa>456787654345671</schr:nr_chipa>
            <schr:data_przyjecia>13/09/2021</schr:data_przyjecia>
            <schr:miejsce_znalezienia mID="m2"></schr:miejsce_znalezienia>
        </schr:zwierze>
    </schr:zwierzeta>

    <!--Spis miejsc znalezienia zwierząt-->
    <schr:miejsca_znalezienia>
        <schr:miejsce m_ID="m1">
            <schr:ulica>Piotrkowska</schr:ulica>
            <schr:kod_pocztowy>92-430</schr:kod_pocztowy>
            <schr:miasto>Lodz</schr:miasto>
        </schr:miejsce>
        <schr:miejsce m_ID="m2">
            <schr:ulica>Wolczanska</schr:ulica>
            <schr:kod_pocztowy>92-423</schr:kod_pocztowy>
            <schr:miasto>Lodz</schr:miasto>
        </schr:miejsce>
    </schr:miejsca_znalezienia>

</schronisko>
```

**my XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.pl/schema"
        xmlns:schr="http://www.example.pl/schema"
        xmlns:pod="https://www.example.org/Podstawy"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="Podstawy.xsd" namespace="https://www.example.org/Podstawy"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="typyElementow.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="schronisko" type="schr:schroniskoType">
        <xs:key name="IDmiejsca">
            <xs:selector xpath="schr:miejsca_znalezienia/schr:miejsce"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@m_ID"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="refDoIDmiejsca" refer="schr:IDmiejsca">
            <xs:selector xpath="schr:zwierzeta/schr:zwierze/schr:miejsce_znalezienia"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@mID"/>
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:key name="numer">
            <xs:selector xpath="schr:zwierzeta/schr:zwierze"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@nr"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="schroniskoType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="autor" type="schr:autorType"/>
            <xs:element name="opis" type="pod:string50"/>
            <xs:element name="zwierzeta" type="schr:zwierzetaType"/>
            <xs:element name="miejsca_znalezienia" type="schr:miejscaznalType"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="autorType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="imie_autora" type="pod:stringWielka"/>
            <xs:element name="nazwisko" type="pod:stringWielka"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="numer_albumu" type="schr:numerAlbumuType"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="zwierzetaType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="zwierze" type="schr:zwierzeType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="zwierzeType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="plec" type="schr:plecType"/>
            <xs:element name="imie" type="pod:stringWielka"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="rasa" type="schr:rasaType"/>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="2">
                <xs:element name="wielkosc" type="schr:wielkoscType"/>
                <xs:element name="waga" type="schr:wagaType"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="wiek" type="pod:int40"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="kolor" type="pod:string15mala"/>
            <xs:element name="nr_chipa" type="schr:nr_chipaType"/>
            <xs:element name="data_przyjecia" type="pod:dataTyp"/>
            <xs:element name="miejsce_znalezienia">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="mID" type="pod:keyType" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="schr:zwierzeAttr"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="miejscaznalType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="miejsce" type="schr:miejsceType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="miejsceType">
        <xs:group ref="schr:adres"/>
        <xs:attribute name="m_ID" use="required" type="pod:keyType" />
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**and typyElementow.XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:pod="https://www.example.org/Podstawy"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="Podstawy.xsd" namespace="https://www.example.org/Podstawy"/>

    <xs:simpleType name="numerAlbumuType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:totalDigits value="6"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="plecType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="F"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="rasaType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="perski"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="syberyjski"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="syjamski"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="owczarek"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="york"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="buldog"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="husky"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="mops"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="wielkoscType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="maly"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="sredni"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="duzy"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="wagaType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="pod:float200">
            <xs:attribute name="jednostka" type="xs:token" default="kg"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="nr_chipaType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
            <xs:totalDigits value="15"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="gatunekType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="kot"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="pies"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:attributeGroup name="zwierzeAttr">
        <xs:attribute name="nr" use="required" type="pod:keyType"/>
        <xs:attribute name="gatunek" type="gatunekType" use="required"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>

    <xs:group name="adres">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ulica" type="pod:stringWielka"/>
            <xs:element name="kod_pocztowy" type="pod:kodpocztowy"/>
            <xs:element name="miasto" type="pod:stringWielka"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

**and Podstawy.XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="https://www.example.org/Podstawy"
        xmlns:pod="https://www.example.org/Podstawy"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="string15mala">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="15"></xs:maxLength>
            <xs:minLength value="3"></xs:minLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="stringWielka">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{3}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{4}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{5}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{6}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{7}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{8}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{9}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{10}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{11}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{12}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{13}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{14}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="string50">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="50"></xs:maxLength>
            <xs:minLength value="10"></xs:minLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="float200">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
            <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="200"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="int40">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="40"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>


    <xs:simpleType name="dataTyp">
        <xs:union>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="pod:listaLiczb">
                    <xs:length value="3"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="listaLiczb">
        <xs:list itemType="pod:liczbyData"/>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="liczbyData">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="31"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="kodpocztowy">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="keyType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-z]{1}-[0-9]{2}"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[a-z]{1}-[0-9]{1}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, change `schronisko` to `schr:schronisko` to leverage the `schr` namespace prefix to place `schronisko` into the target namespace of your XSD, `xmlns:schr="http://www.example.pl/schema"`.